# Why is $ \nabla V = (dV/d|r|) \nabla (|r|) $ where V is a function of r?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Why is $ \nabla V = (dV/d|r|) \nabla (|r|) $ ? I don't understand where the elements of the RHS are coming from ?

Comment: can you please expand more on the terms and their meaning? We can guess, but it would be better with more context

Comment: for example do we have $V(r)$? and what about $V(r(t))$ and $r(t)$ ?

Comment: @Euler_Salter V is the potential and it is defines as V(r) , I am not sure about V(r(t)) but I guess that would also be true since the position vector is a function of time ?

Comment: also to be more precise it is V(|r|) @Euler_Salter

Comment: if it was $V(|r(t)|)$ maybe you could have $\nabla V(|r(t)|) = \frac{dV}{d|r|} \frac{d|r|}{dt} = \frac{dV}{d|r|} \nabla|r|$ ? But this is probably very wrong tbh

Comment: @SimpleArt: You can not divide vectors. Even if they use gradient notation but are not gradients. $$∇\|r\|=(\frac∂{∂x},\frac∂{∂y},\frac∂{∂z})\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}.$$

Comment: @LutzL Ok.  I honestly don't know much about this area of math yet.

Comment: @Euler_Salter : No, one is a scalar derivative of a scalar function, the other is a multi-variate derivative. You can put these terms together as $$\frac{d}{dt} V(|r(t)|)=∇V(|r(t)|)·\dot r=V'(|r(t)|)·∇|r(t)|·\dot r.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is just the chain rule. The inner function is the norm, $g(r)=\|r\|$, the outer function $V$ is just a scalar function, so that the derivative of the composition is
$$
(V\circ g)'=(V'∘g)·g'
$$
One can now also write the Jacobian of $g$ (ab-)using gradient notation, $g'(r)=∇g(r)=∇\|r\|$. The full expression also has a vector valued derivative, so that one can summarily write
$$
∇ V(\|r\|)=V'(\|r\|)·∇\|r\|.
$$